# File created with Storage Access Framework is greyed out afterwards for selection when containing a (1)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file, storage-access-framework

I created a file with

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType(FILE_TYPE); // text/*
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "vocable_export.csv");


startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE);
// writing to received URI
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(es.file, "w");));
```

Now when I try to select that file again, I get the file I created greyed out, such that I can't select it. I tried killing the app in case I didn't close the file correctly, but that didn't help. I can select & open files dragged into the emulator perfectly fine. What does work is renaming the file so it doesn't contain the (1) at the end any more.

Open code

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType(FILE_TYPE); // text/*

startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FILE);
```

[image]

Comment: `OutputStreamWriter(context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(es.file....` ?? What is es.file?

Comment: `intent.setType(FILE_TYPE);` ?? What is FILE_TYPE? Please post code that we can read.

Comment: @blackapps Please stop spamming the comments. I adjusted the tags. As you can see for yourself it doesn't matter from where es comes or which filetype I set. The (1) at the end makes the problem.

Comment: And all the things i asked do matter.

Comment: No it doesn't matter where the URI comes from (the callback..). Selecting the files is only blocked when it's having a (1) at the end, renaming helps perfectly fine, so it might be the mimetype (but why is it showing up at all then, non-mimetype matches aren't shown otherwise) or simply the fact android doesn't want me to open weirdly formed filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android simply seems to fail displaying such files when a (1) is appended on writing a second file with the same name. Renaming such files will get them to show up again in a selectable state.